# How to declare file locations in another function?

Tags: c, file

I have multiple files. So I decided to use the file declaration in a separate function. Is this is a perfect way? Because it is not working what I want. I want to declare the files multiple times in a easy way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char fileLocation(FILE * fname, char *name, char *mode){
  fname = fopen(name, mode);
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  FILE * ft1;
  fileLocation(ft1, "file.csv", "r");
  char string[200];

  while(fgets(string, 200, ft1)){
    printf("%s\n", string);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem better than "not working". What error or incorrect behaviour are you asking about? One thing to note: `fname` is local to the function. Setting it in the function does not change the caller's value. But since you have not described the exact problem so can't say whether that is the issue you are asking about.

Comment: Just guessing here, but it's the old and common "passing arguments by value" problem. The argument variables in a function are *local* variables, whose value is *copied* from the values used when calling the function. Modifying an argument variable only modifies the local copy, not the original value (or variable). Please research *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Not related, but your names are strange. A function called `filelocation` that actually opens the file, variable named `fname` that does not store a name but a `FILE*` ... These are good conditions to confuse future readers

Comment: @kaylum My problem is that it is not working. Plus I don't want to declare files again and again but instead declare it in a separate function to use multiple times in different functions.

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. Does it crash? Does it produce wrong output? Does it explode the computer? What exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `fileLocation` function is supposed to do. Even if it was written correctly, it would not do more than `fopen` does. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me

Comment: @Jabberwocky Bro I am just trying to read and use multiple times in different functions.

Comment: What is the type of `name`? Is it a string or only a single character?

Comment: @Dazthaak sorry I don't understand. Just open the file with `fopen`. What's wrong with that? Apparently I'm not the only one here who is puzzled

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is a string

Comment: @Dazthaak Is `char name` really a string? Really? Wouldn't a string be something like `char *name`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used *name. Now it is not giving me an error but also it is not printing when using `while(fgets(...))`

Comment: And that is the issue I mentioned in my first comment. `fname` is a *local* variable. All assignments to it will be lost when the `fileLocation` function ends.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So how to deal with it?

Comment: @Dazthaak now you mention `while(fgets(...))` which does not even appear in the question. Please [edit] and show a [mcve]. And explain what your code is supposed to do. We need a broader picture in order to be able to help you.

Comment: You are trying to replace `FILE * ft1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");` with `FILE * ft1; fileLocation(ft1, "file.csv", "r");`. Why? That's not shorter and it doesn't remove redundancy. It looks like a misunderstanding if you believe that the second solution is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
FILE *fileLocation(char *name, char *mode){
  return fopen(name, mode);
}

int main(){
  FILE *f = fileLocation("file.csv", "r");

  if (f == NULL) {
     // handle error (file could not be opened)
  }
  
  char string[200];
  while(fgets(string, 200, ft1)){
    printf("%s\n", string);
  }

  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

or maybe this:

```
void fileLocation(FILE **file, char *name, char *mode){
  *file = fopen(name, mode);
}

int main(){
  FILE *f;
  fileLocation(&f, "file.csv", "r");

  ...
}
```

This works, but it's pretty pointless because you could just call `fopen` from main.

Actually this should be good enough:

```
int main()
{
   FILE *f = fopen("file.csv", "r");
   ...
```

Comment: I'd be curious why you think that calling simple `fopen` is not good enough.

Comment: I can call fopen from main but the I have many files and each one has different folders in which the file is present. That's why I don't why I don't want to write all the file location every time.

Comment: The location of the file is `/home/bilal/Documents/Project/Project2/file.csv` I just shortened the code to make you understand.

Comment: @Dazthaak then I don't know how my answer solves your problem. You have clearly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) <<-- read this, it's interesting, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

Well your first error and the subsequent warning is quite obvious..

`int fileLocation(FILE * fname, char name, char mode){`

Your name should be a char *  as should be the mode

As for the ft1, maybe you should declare it.

This compiles with only one warning about the return value of the fileLocation function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int fileLocation(FILE * fname, char *name, char *mode){
  fname = fopen(name, mode);
}

int main(){
  FILE ft1;
  fileLocation(&ft1, "file.csv", "r");
}
```

Maybe it should return something ?

- Code status of the fopen function and then treat it in the main function?
- The file descriptor itself ?

Your choice, depending on your intention..

Comment: @vipin-varghese : thanks for your proposition. At first I had done something equivalent. Then I removed them because at the end we don't know what is te intention of the author. It's his choice. 
Maybe the fileLocation function will expand, and many return codes will make sense, maybe it's only that and it does not even need to exist. 
Thats why I chose not to write them.

Comment: @freeflyer thanks for reject and update as a comment. There is an update from the author `I am just trying to read and use multiple times in different functions`. which clearly showcases his intention is to read multiple files and showcase content. Based on this input he is simply trying to have a 2-dimensional array holding file names and printing contents per file. So yes one needs to check the return values for fopen and display the content that is read.